# Why are my PHP $_SESSION[sessionvar] getting lost between pages in on iPhone?

Tags: php, iphone, session

I'm using the basic framework of the a php login form provided here:  http://www.html-form-guide.com/php-form/php-login-form.html

It works great when I am on a Mac or PC. When login from an iPhone, the $_SESSION array is empty, so the identify of the logged in user is lost, and the system wasn't to redirect to login.php.

How can I prevent the $_SESSION array from getting wiped out?

Comment: In the login page, the $_SESSION[sessionvar] is set like this:  $_SESSION[$this->GetLoginSessionVar()] = $username; On the next page, $_SESSION[$this->GetLoginSessionVar()] is empty.. only on iPhone.

Comment: do you mean session_id is empty? session  vars are stored on your server

Comment: answered here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1857826/how-can-i-create-and-maintain-authentication-sessions-on-an-iphone

Comment: Nope.  I'm not talking about session_id.  It's $_SESSION[$this-GetLoginSessionVar()] which is set on one page, and blank on the next, but only on iPhone.

Comment: I had similar problems in the past but not using an iPhone. In my case the client (Flash app) was not able to store cookies, so PHP could not identify the session (there was no cookie to tell the session id). I solved the problem passing the session id as a GET parameter on every link/form in the app.

Comment: Hmm.. Is that really an answer?  Someone just refers them to HTTP Cookies, with no mention of why, or if/why $_SESSION won't work.  I guess I could try to rewrite around using cookies, but I'd like to know why $_SESSION isn't working.

Comment: I can probably make this work with adding GET parameters.  Ugh!

Comment: I can enable cookies on my iPhone, http://rf.com/how-to/how-to-enable-cookies-on-the-iphone/.  That solves the problem but it seems unreasonable to require everyone to enable cookies on their phones.  I think I need to look at other options.  GET parameters is the leading option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your iPhone browser does not have cookies enabled. Due to security reasons, the PHP sessions default to cookie usage, however there is a second way using a [GET parameter as well, often called SID](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php). Make use of that get parameter and you should be fine for cookie-less browsers.

Comment: If you do go with the GET solution, please be aware that anyone can type whatever parameter they want to "guess" other people's session IDs. It's not a show-stopper, but you should give some thought to how you're going to make that foolproof.

Comment: @ZachRattner: Same applies to cookies, you can guess them as well and just provide the cookie in the request. If javascript is enabled, cookies can be even injected.